# Linedash on OpenLayers 7 and WebglVectorLayer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, openlayers

I have a problem with the implementation of webgl on my react application. I have to implement webgl to address performance problems, the first results are very promising but I can not manage the line dash on my trajectories.

The examples do not show this possbility yet essential in OpenLayer and I fail to reproduce the dashed line.

[Links](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-vector-layer.html) to webgl layer documentation

I created a WebGLLayer class that allows to receive style in parameter

```
export default class WebGlLayer<VectorSourceType extends Source> extends Layer<
    VectorSourceType,
    WebGLVectorLayerRenderer
> {
    Style: Istyle;
    constructor(options: Options<VectorSourceType>, style: Istyle) {
        super(options)
        this.style = style;
    }
    createRenderer(): WebGLVectorLayerRenderer {
        return new WebGLVectorLayerRenderer(this, this.style);
    }
}
```

I then use it in my react components as follows:

```
    const [trajectoryLineSource] = useState(new VectorSource<LineString>({});
    const [trajectoryLineLayer] = useState(
        new WebGlLayer(
            {
                source: trajectoryLineSource,
            },
            applyWebGlLineStyle,
        ),
    );
```

*applyWebGlLineStyle* consists of the trajectory style properties:

```
export const applyWebGlLineStyle = {
    stroke: {
        attributes: {
            color: function () {
                const color = [...asArray(theme.palette.warning.dark)];
                return packColor(color);
            },
            width: function () {
                return 2;
            },
        },
    },
};
```

All works well but I don’t find any lineDash proriety as in the style elements of the VectorLayer.

Does anyone have a lead or a solution on that?

Thank you in advance for your help :)